# Mapping mouse coordinates with context

Tags: javascript, mapping

I have a webgl being rendered on a canvas element. After it is rendered I want to allow user to draw on it with a mouse (rect for example). Since the getContext does not work for the second time, I added another transparent canvas on top of my webgl canvas and I am want to draw a rect with a mouse on the transparent canvas. The problem is that the coordinates in a mousedown event are very different to the context corrdinates

My canvas are as below

```
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="webglCanvas" tabindex='1'></canvas>
  <canvas id="transCanvas" tabindex='1'></canvas>
</div>
```

to get context

```
var $canvas1 = document.getElementById('transCanvas');
var ctx = $canvas1.getContext("2d");
```

mouse down event of transCanvas. Please note that I have hard coded the rect at the moment on mouse down event. Later I will do it on mouse move etc. This works fine on my canvas and I can see the rect on my screen. But the mouse coordinates eg e.clientX and e.clientY are in hundereds and go off the screen?

```
function handleCanvasMouseMove(e) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = '#F30';
   ctx.fillRect(75, 75, 75, 75);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, you're converting NormalizedDeviceCoords with a range of [-1..1] in each axis to a position on screen. All the transformations you applied takes the model-space vert and essentially put it in a cube of size 2, centred on the origin.

So... I imagine you'd also like to get back mouse-coordinates in this same space. If so, it's just a matter of constructing a matrix and then multiplying the screen-space position by this matrix to get x,y in the range of [-1..1]

When I've done similar things in the past, I've used a series of transformations as follows:

```
function makeClipToPixMat(width,height)
{
    // flip the Y
    let s1 = mat4.scaling(1,-1,1);

    // translate so space is now [0..2]
    let t1 = mat4.translation(1,1,0);

    // scale so space is now [0..width], [0..height]
    let s2 = mat4.scaling(width/2,height/2,1);

    // s1, then t1, then s2 are applied to the input coords
    let result = mat4.matrixByMatrix(s1,t1);
    result = result.multiply(s2);

    return result;
}
```

But as you'll notice from the name, it's a mapping in the wrong direction. We want to map screen-coords to NDC, but this code does the opposite. What now then? Simple - either invert the matrix or determine the series of transforms needed and construct a matrix that will do them all in one go. It's a simple enough transform, that a matrix-inversion seems like a fantastically expensive way to do something so simple.

In fact, here's the function I use. Inversion works fine too and can decrease the code size at the expensive of run-time.

```
function pixelsToClipspace(width,height)
{
    let scaleMat = mat4.scaling( 1/(width/2), -1/(height/2), 1);
    let translateMat = mat4.translation(-width/2, -height/2, 0); //.transpose();
    let mat = mat4.matrixByMatrix(translateMat, scaleMat);
    return mat;
}
```

Since I've some time at the moment, I hacked together a quick demo for you. Shame, there's 380 lines of code for the vec4 and the matrix, yet only about 35 for the demo. :laughs: That said, it perfectly illustrates how expensive and complicated the matrix .inverse() function is.

LASTLY: please note, I do not make any claims as to the accuracy of any of the code included yet not utilized. Exercises like this one benefit each of us. You get some understanding, I get some more debug test-cases. :) The matrices are column-major (like all good GL ones should be)

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

let s2Clip = null;

function onLoaded(evt)
{
 let can = document.querySelector('canvas');
 s2Clip = pixelsToClipspace(can.clientWidth, can.clientHeight); // use clienWidth/clientHeight to avoid CSS scaling problems
 can.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouse, false);
}


function onMouse(evt)
{
 var rawPos = new vec4(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY, 0, 1);   
 var trPos = s2Clip.timesVector(rawPos);
 document.getElementById('rawMouse').innerText = `${rawPos.x}, ${rawPos.y}`
 document.getElementById('transMouse').innerText = `${trPos.x.toFixed(2)}, ${trPos.y.toFixed(2)}`
}

function pixelsToClipspace(width,height)
{
 let scaleMat = mat4.scaling( 1/(width/2), -1/(height/2), 1);
 let translateMat = mat4.translation(-width/2, -height/2, 0); //.transpose();
 let mat = mat4.matrixByMatrix(translateMat, scaleMat);
 return mat;
}
// </script>



// <script origSrc='vector.js'>
class vec4
{
 // w=0 for dir (cant translate), w=1 for pos (can)
 constructor(x=0,y=0,z=0,w=0){this.values = [x,y,z,w];}
 clone(){ return new vec4(this.x,this.y,this.z,this.w); }
 get x(){return this.values[0];}
 get y(){return this.values[1];}
 get z(){return this.values[2];}
 get w(){return this.values[3];}
 set x(x){this.values[0]=x;}
 set y(y){this.values[1]=y;}
 set z(z){this.values[2]=z;}
 set w(w){this.values[3]=w;}
 get length(){return Math.hypot( ...this.values ); }
 normalize(){ var l = this.length; if (l>1e-6) {this.x/=l;this.y/=l;this.z/=l;this.w/=l;} return this;}
 scaleBy(scalar){this.x*=scalar;this.y*=scalar;this.z*=scalar;this.w*=scalar;return this;}
 divBy(scalar){this.x/=scalar;this.y/=scalar;this.z/=scalar;this.w/=scalar;return this;}
 add(other){return new vec4(this.x+other.x, this.y+other.y, this.z+other.z, this.w+other.w);}
 sub(other){return new vec4(this.x-other.x, this.y-other.y, this.z-other.z, this.w-other.w);}
 get xyz(){return new vec3(this.x,this.y,this.z);}
 
 toStringN(n){return `[${pad(this.x,n)}, ${pad(this.y,n)}, ${pad(this.z,n)}, ${pad(this.w,n)}]`;}
 
 timesMatrix(matrix)
 {
  let m0 = matrix.getCol(0), m1 = matrix.getCol(1), m2 = matrix.getCol(2), m3 = matrix.getCol(3);
  return new vec4(
   (m0.x*this.x) + (m1.x*this.y) + m2.x*this.z + m3.x*this.w,
   (m0.y*this.x) + (m1.y*this.y) + m2.y*this.z + m3.y*this.w,
   (m0.z*this.x) + (m1.z*this.y) + m2.z*this.z + m3.z*this.w,
   (m0.w*this.x) + (m1.w*this.y) + m2.w*this.z + m3.w*this.w  
  );
 }
 
 vecByMatrix(m) /// operator * (matrix, vector)
 {
  let mc0 = m.getCol(0), mc1=m.getCol(1), mc2=m.getCol(2), mc3=m.getCol(3);
  return new vec4(
   (mc0.x * this.x) + (mc1.x * this.y) + (mc2.x * this.z) + (mc3.x * this.w),
   (mc0.y * this.x) + (mc1.y * this.y) + (mc2.y * this.z) + (mc3.y * this.w),
   (mc0.z * this.x) + (mc1.z * this.y) + (mc2.z * this.z) + (mc3.z * this.w),
   (mc0.w * this.x) + (mc1.w * this.y) + (mc2.w * this.z) + (mc3.w * this.w),
  );
 }
 
 matrixByVec(m) /// operator * (vector, matrix)
 {
  let mCol0 = m.getCol(0), mCol1=m.getCol(1), mCol2=m.getCol(2), mCol3=m.getCol(3);
  return new vec4(
   this.x*mCol0.x + this.y*mCol0.y + this.z*mCol0.z + this.w*mCol0.w,
   this.x*mCol1.x + this.y*mCol1.y + this.z*mCol1.z + this.w*mCol1.w,
   this.x*mCol2.x + this.y*mCol2.y + this.z*mCol2.z + this.w*mCol2.w,
   this.x*mCol3.x + this.y*mCol3.y + this.z*mCol3.z + this.w*mCol3.w
  );
 }
}


class mat4
{
 constructor(xVec4=new vec4(1,0,0,0), yVec4=new vec4(0,1,0,0), zVec4=new vec4(0,0,1,0), wVec4=new vec4(0,0,0,1) )
 {
  this.columns = [ 
       xVec4.clone(), 
       yVec4.clone(), 
       zVec4.clone(), 
       wVec4.clone() 
      ];
 }
 getCol(colIndex) {return this.columns[colIndex];}
 setCol(colIndex, newVec) {this.columns[colIndex] = newVec.clone();}
 
 setIdentity()
 {
  let x=new vec4(1,0,0,0);
  let y=new vec4(0,1,0,0);
  let z=new vec4(0,0,1,0);
  let w=new vec4(0,0,0,1);
  this.setCol(0,x);
  this.setCol(0,y);
  this.setCol(0,z);
  this.setCol(0,w);
  return this;
 }
 
 static clone(other)
 {
  var result = new mat4( other.columns[0], other.columns[1], other.columns[2], other.columns[3] );
  return result;
 }
 clone()
 {
  return mat4.clone(this);
 }
 
 static scaling(sx=1,sy=1,sz=1)
 {
  let x = new vec4(sx,0,0,);
  let y = new vec4(0,sy,0,);
  let z = new vec4(0,0,sz,);
  let w = new vec4(0,0,0,1);
  return new mat4(x,y,z,w);
 }
 
 static translation(tx=0,ty=0,tz=0)
 {
  let X = new vec4(1,0,0,tx);
  let Y = new vec4(0,1,0,ty);
  let Z = new vec4(0,0,1,tz);
  let W = new vec4(0,0,0,1);
  return new mat4(X,Y,Z,W);
 }
 
 static matrixByMatrix(m1, m2)
 {
  let mCol0 = m2.getCol(0), mCol1=m2.getCol(1), mCol2=m2.getCol(2), mCol3=m2.getCol(3);
  let X = mCol0.vecByMatrix(m1);
  let Y = mCol1.vecByMatrix(m1);
  let Z = mCol2.vecByMatrix(m1);
  let W = mCol3.vecByMatrix(m1);
  return new mat4(X,Y,Z,W);
 }
 
 static matTimeMat(m1,m2)
 {
  let mc0=m2.getCol(0),mc1=m2.getCol(1),mc2=m2.getCol(2),mc3=m2.getCol(3);
  let x = m1.timesVector(mc0);
  let y = m1.timesVector(mc1);
  let z = m1.timesVector(mc2);
  let w = m1.timesVector(mc3);
  return new mat4(x,y,z,w);
 }
 
 multiply(other,shouldPrepend=false)
 {
  var a=this,b=other,c;
  if (shouldPrepend===true){a=other;b=this;}
  c = mat4.matrixByMatrix(a,b);
  this.columns = c.columns.slice();
  return this;
 }
 
 translate(tx=0,ty=0,tz=0)
 {
  return this.multiply( mat4.translation(tx,ty,tz) );
 }
 
 setScale(sx=1,sy=1,sz=1)
 {
  let x = new vec4(sx,0,0,0);
  let y = new vec4(0,sy,0,0);
  let z = new vec4(0,0,sz,0);
  let w = new vec4(0,0,0,1);
  let tmp = new mat4(x,y,z,w);
  this.columns = tmp.columns.slice();
  return this;
 }
 setTrans(tx=0,ty=0,tz=0)
 {
  let x = new vec4( 1, 0, 0, 0);
  let y = new vec4( 0, 1, 0, 0);
  let z = new vec4( 0, 0, 1, 0);
  let w = new vec4( tx, ty, tz, 1);
  var tmp = new mat4(x,y,z,w);
  this.columns = tmp.columns.slice();
  return this;
 }
 setRotX(degrees)
 {
  let cosa = Math.cos(degrees * 3.141/180);
  let sina = Math.sin(degrees * 3.141/180);
  let x = new vec4(1,0,0,0);
  let y = new vec4(0,cosa,sina,0)
  let z = new vec4(0,-sina,cosa,0);
  let w = new vec4(0,0,0,1);
  let tmp = new mat4(x,y,z,w);
  this.columns = tmp.columns.slice();
  return this;
 }
 setRotY(degrees)
 {
  let cosa = Math.cos(degrees * 3.141/180);
  let sina = Math.sin(degrees * 3.141/180);
  let x = new vec4( cosa, 0,-sina,0);
  let y = new vec4(    0, 1,   0, 0)
  let z = new vec4( sina, 0,cosa, 0);
  let w = new vec4(    0, 0,   0, 1);
  let tmp = new mat4(x,y,z,w);
  this.columns = tmp.columns.slice();
  return this;
 }
 setRotZ(degrees)
 {
  let cosa = Math.cos(degrees * 3.141/180);
  let sina = Math.sin(degrees * 3.141/180);
  let x = new vec4(cosa,sina,0,0);
  let y = new vec4(-sina,cosa,0,0)
  let z = new vec4(0,0,1,0);
  let w = new vec4(0,0,0,1);
  let tmp = new mat4(x,y,z,w);
  this.columns = tmp.columns.slice();
  return this;
 }
 
 scaleEach(sX=1,sY=1,sZ=1,shouldPrepend=false)
 {
  let tmp = new mat4();
  let X = tmp.getCol(0);
  X.x = sX;
  tmp.setCol(0,X);
  let Y = tmp.getCol(1);
  Y.y = sY;
  tmp.setCol(1,Y);
  let Z = tmp.getCol(2);
  Z.z = sZ;
  tmp.setCol(2,Z);
  return this.multiply(tmp, shouldPrepend);
  //return this;
 }
 
 scaleAll(sXYZ, shouldPrepend=false)
 {
  return this.scaleEach(sXYZ,sXYZ,sXYZ,shouldPrepend);
  //return this;
 }
 
 /*
 translate(tX=0, tY=0, tZ=0, shouldPrepend=false)
 {
  let tmp = new mat4();
  let W = tmp.getCol(3);
  W.x = tX;
  W.y = tY;
  W.z = tZ;
  tmp.setCol(3,W);
  return this.multiply(tmp, shouldPrepend);
 }
 */
 
 timesVector(vector)
 {
  let m0=this.getCol(0), m1=this.getCol(1), m2=this.getCol(2), m3=this.getCol(3);
  return new vec4(
   (vector.x*m0.x) + (vector.y*m0.y) + (vector.z*m0.z) + (vector.w*m0.w),
   (vector.x*m1.x) + (vector.y*m1.y) + (vector.z*m1.z) + (vector.w*m1.w),
   (vector.x*m2.x) + (vector.y*m2.y) + (vector.z*m2.z) + (vector.w*m2.w),
   (vector.x*m3.x) + (vector.y*m3.y) + (vector.z*m3.z) + (vector.w*m3.w)
  );
 }
 
 toString()
 {
  let result = '', row=0,col=0;
  result  = `[ ${this.getCol(0).x}, ${this.getCol(1).x}, ${this.getCol(2).x}, ${this.getCol(3).x} ]\n`;
  result += `[ ${this.getCol(0).y}, ${this.getCol(1).y}, ${this.getCol(2).y}, ${this.getCol(3).y} ]\n`;
  result += `[ ${this.getCol(0).z}, ${this.getCol(1).z}, ${this.getCol(2).z}, ${this.getCol(3).z} ]\n`;
  result += `[ ${this.getCol(0).w}, ${this.getCol(1).w}, ${this.getCol(2).w}, ${this.getCol(3).w} ]\n`;
  return result;
 }
 
 toStrN(n)
 {
  return this.toStringN(n);
 }
 
 toStringN(nDigs)
 {
  let result = '';
  let xVec=this.getCol(0).clone(), 
   yVec=this.getCol(1).clone(), 
   zVec=this.getCol(2).clone(), 
   wVec=this.getCol(3).clone();
   
  let vs=[xVec,yVec,zVec,wVec];
  
  for (var i=0,n=vs.length; i<n; i++)
  {
   vs[i].x = pad(vs[i].x, nDigs);
   vs[i].y = pad(vs[i].y, nDigs);
   vs[i].z = pad(vs[i].z, nDigs);
   vs[i].w = pad(vs[i].w, nDigs);
  }
  result  = `[ ${xVec.x}, ${yVec.x}, ${zVec.x}, ${wVec.x} ]\n`;
  result += `[ ${xVec.y}, ${yVec.y}, ${zVec.y}, ${wVec.y} ]\n`;
  result += `[ ${xVec.z}, ${yVec.z}, ${zVec.z}, ${wVec.z} ]\n`;
  result += `[ ${xVec.w}, ${yVec.w}, ${zVec.w}, ${wVec.w} ]\n`;
  return result;
 }
 asRows(nDigs=2)
 {
  let result = '',xVec=this.getCol(0),yVec=this.getCol(1),zVec=this.getCol(2),wVec=this.getCol(3);
  result = `[${xVec.x.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${xVec.y.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${xVec.z.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${xVec.w.toFixed(nDigs)}]\n`;
  result += `[${yVec.x.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${yVec.y.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${yVec.z.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${yVec.w.toFixed(nDigs)}]\n`;
  result += `[${zVec.x.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${zVec.y.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${zVec.z.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${zVec.w.toFixed(nDigs)}]\n`;
  result += `[${wVec.x.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${wVec.y.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${wVec.z.toFixed(nDigs)}, ${wVec.w.toFixed(nDigs)}]\n`;
  return result;
 }

 transpose()
 {
  let X=this.getCol(0), Y=this.getCol(1), Z=this.getCol(2), W=this.getCol(3);
  
  let tmp = new mat4(
       new vec4(X.x,Y.x,Z.x,W.x),
       new vec4(X.y,Y.y,Z.y,W.y),
       new vec4(X.z,Y.z,Z.z,W.z),
       new vec4(X.w,Y.w,Z.w,W.w),
      );
  this.setCol(0,X);
  this.setCol(1,Y);
  this.setCol(2,Z);
  this.setCol(3,W);
  return tmp; //this.copy(tmp);
 }
 
 inverse()
 {
  let X = this.getCol(0), Y = this.getCol(1), Z = this.getCol(2), W = this.getCol(3);
  let m00=X.x, m01=X.y, m02=X.z, m03=X.w,
   m10=Y.x, m11=Y.y, m12=Y.z, m13=Y.w,
   m20=Z.x, m21=Z.y, m22=Z.z, m23=Z.w,
   m30=W.x, m31=W.y, m32=W.z, m33=W.w;
   
  let tmp_0=m22*m33, tmp_1=m32*m23, tmp_2=m12*m33,
   tmp_3=m32*m13, tmp_4=m12*m23, tmp_5=m22*m13,
   tmp_6=m02*m33, tmp_7=m32*m03, tmp_8=m02*m23,
   tmp_9=m22*m03, tmp_10=m02*m13,tmp_11=m12*m03,
   tmp_12=m20*m31,tmp_13=m30*m21,tmp_14=m10*m31,
   tmp_15=m30*m11,tmp_16=m10*m21,tmp_17=m20*m11,
   tmp_18=m00*m31,tmp_19=m30*m01,tmp_20=m00*m21,
   tmp_21=m20*m01,tmp_22=m00*m11,tmp_23=m10*m01;

   var t0 = (tmp_0 * m11 + tmp_3 * m21 + tmp_4 * m31) - (tmp_1 * m11 + tmp_2 * m21 + tmp_5 * m31);
   var t1 = (tmp_1 * m01 + tmp_6 * m21 + tmp_9 * m31) - (tmp_0 * m01 + tmp_7 * m21 + tmp_8 * m31);
   var t2 = (tmp_2 * m01 + tmp_7 * m11 + tmp_10 * m31) - (tmp_3 * m01 + tmp_6 * m11 + tmp_11 * m31);
   var t3 = (tmp_5 * m01 + tmp_8 * m11 + tmp_11 * m21) - (tmp_4 * m01 + tmp_9 * m11 + tmp_10 * m21);

   var d = 1.0 / (m00 * t0 + m10 * t1 + m20 * t2 + m30 * t3);

   let Xo = new vec4(d*t0, d*t1, d*t2, d*t3);
   //      d * t0,
   //      d * t1,
   //      d * t2,
   //      d * t3,

   let Yo = new vec4(
          d * ((tmp_1 * m10 + tmp_2 * m20 + tmp_5 * m30) - (tmp_0 * m10 + tmp_3 * m20 + tmp_4 * m30)),
          d * ((tmp_0 * m00 + tmp_7 * m20 + tmp_8 * m30) - (tmp_1 * m00 + tmp_6 * m20 + tmp_9 * m30)),
          d * ((tmp_3 * m00 + tmp_6 * m10 + tmp_11 * m30) - (tmp_2 * m00 + tmp_7 * m10 + tmp_10 * m30)),
          d * ((tmp_4 * m00 + tmp_9 * m10 + tmp_10 * m20) - (tmp_5 * m00 + tmp_8 * m10 + tmp_11 * m20))
       );
       
   let Zo = new vec4(
          d * ((tmp_12 * m13 + tmp_15 * m23 + tmp_16 * m33) - (tmp_13 * m13 + tmp_14 * m23 + tmp_17 * m33)),
          d * ((tmp_13 * m03 + tmp_18 * m23 + tmp_21 * m33) - (tmp_12 * m03 + tmp_19 * m23 + tmp_20 * m33)),
          d * ((tmp_14 * m03 + tmp_19 * m13 + tmp_22 * m33) - (tmp_15 * m03 + tmp_18 * m13 + tmp_23 * m33)),
          d * ((tmp_17 * m03 + tmp_20 * m13 + tmp_23 * m23) - (tmp_16 * m03 + tmp_21 * m13 + tmp_22 * m23))
       );
       
   let Wo = new vec4(
          d * ((tmp_14 * m22 + tmp_17 * m32 + tmp_13 * m12) - (tmp_16 * m32 + tmp_12 * m12 + tmp_15 * m22)),
          d * ((tmp_20 * m32 + tmp_12 * m02 + tmp_19 * m22) - (tmp_18 * m22 + tmp_21 * m32 + tmp_13 * m02)),
          d * ((tmp_18 * m12 + tmp_23 * m32 + tmp_15 * m02) - (tmp_22 * m32 + tmp_14 * m02 + tmp_19 * m12)),
          d * ((tmp_22 * m22 + tmp_16 * m02 + tmp_21 * m12) - (tmp_20 * m12 + tmp_23 * m22 + tmp_17 * m02))
       );
   this.columns = [Xo,Yo,Zo,Wo];
   return this;
 }
}

function pad(num, n)
{
 let str = num.toFixed(n);
 if (num >= 0)
  str = " " + str;
 return str;
}
```

```css
canvas
{
 background-color: #333;
 cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <canvas width='300' height='300'></canvas><br>
 <div>Screen Coords of mouse: <span id='rawMouse'></span></div>
 <div>(2d) NDC of mouse: <span id='transMouse'></span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: "you're converting NormalizedDeviceCoords with a range of [-1..1]" sorry but where do you get that from ? I think OP is working with standard canvas context and vanilla JS

Comment: @Apolo - from the post we each read at the top of the page, in which it's clearly stated that webgl is used. (the first sentence of the post!- "I have a webgl being rendered on a canvas element")

Comment: @enhzflep but I am trying to draw on the canvas that does not have webgl. It just sits on top?

Comment: @user2837961 - well in that case, I suggest you do what should have done from the start - you should include the minimal code required to reproduce the problem. Questions without this aspect attended to are often unanswerable. If you read the HelpCenter, you;'ll surely encounter the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which explains what some of the expectations placed on you are.

Answer (score 0):

I've put explanations as comments in the code

```js
// Canvas viewport (4:3)
const DRAW_WIDTH = 800;
const DRAW_HEIGHT = 600;

const RECT_SIZE = 10;
const RECT_FILL = 'black';

let canvas, ctx;

function init() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  // setup canvas drawing space
  // this will give an aspect-ratio to the canvas
  canvas.setAttribute('width', DRAW_WIDTH);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', DRAW_HEIGHT);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // attach listener
  canvas.addEventListener("click", onMouseDown);
}

function onMouseDown(e) {
  // get canvas position and size infos:
  const bbox = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const {
    x: canvasX,
    y: canvasY,
    width: canvasW,
    height: canvasH
  } = bbox;
  // mouse click position
  const {
    clientX: mouseX,
    clientY: mouseY
  } = e;

  // compute ratio between drawing size (viewport) and actual size
  const widthRatio = DRAW_WIDTH / canvasW;
  // compute x relative to your canvas
  const relativeX = (mouseX - canvasX);
  // I advise you to use int values when drawing on canvas
  // thus Math.round
  const finalX = Math.round(widthRatio * relativeX);

  // same for Y-axis
  const heightRatio = DRAW_HEIGHT / canvasH;
  const relativeY = (mouseY - canvasY);
  const finalY = Math.round(heightRatio * relativeY);

  // draw something with that:
  ctx.fillStyle = RECT_FILL;
  ctx.rect(finalX - RECT_SIZE / 2, finalY - RECT_SIZE / 2, RECT_SIZE, RECT_SIZE);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

init();
```

```css
/* set canvas width in the document */

canvas {
  width: 80vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  background: coral;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: The op almost certainly IS working in NDC. How are you going to get the -1 part with simple scaling??

Comment: I get your point about webgl, but I don't think I need that to fulfill to main goal of mapping mouse coord to canvas 2d coord

Comment: @Apollo - I guess we'll find out when the OP returns to the thread with a few more details or heaven-forbid, a 'working' example. We shouldn't have to guess what the issue is.